# Fancybox type popup window that's not an iframe

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, javascript

I'm a bit stuck and need some help to get me going in the right direction.

I'm trying to do something similar to the lightbox style popup on this website: http://cargocollective.com/montessori

I want to build a popup window, with the scrollbars off to the side at the normal location (which, to my knowledge, rules out an iframe), and a URL that updates.

I can figure out how the css will work, and that I can update the URL with html5 orjs, but here is where I am stuck:

**What is the best way for me to bring the information from a project page into the popup window with Wordpress? Is it AJAX? Is there a way to do it with php? Or is an iframe the right method?**

I tried using Fancybox, but the scrollbars end up in the page.

Any help would be appreciated!!